# How to add a "viewed" icon to pages that are visited

Tags: 7, flags

I have a Drupal 7 site where I have a bunch of videos and I could use a little help with understanding the best way to show a small icon next to my video links after a visitor has viewed it. Is there a way to do this if they are anonymous visitors? My site does not have user accounts. Also, each of my videos are on a separate page and have a unique url.

I've looked briefly into the Flag Module, but I'm not sure if this work work as I don't want viewers to click on anything. I only to track their browsing.

Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion using a cookie could be a nice way to accomplish that need. (Maybe even the only way).   A quick search came up with the `user_cookie_save` function >> https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_cookie_save/7

Use it to save the cookie with the video URL or another identifier and read that cookie when loading the page and set the viewed flag.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find the simplest way (for anonymous users) is to use the **:visited** CSS selector.

```
.video a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  padding-right: 16px;
}
.video a:visited {
  background-image: url(icon.png);
}
```

Comment: I thought this was a brilliant idea till I came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202856/background-image-for-visited-links. It also doesn't work for me on all browsers. Thanks anway!

Comment: Yeah that's annoying. I've written a cookie version in the past too that just stores a serialized array of node ID's. That's what Rotem is suggesting.